# Network wide activity feeds?

Tags: feature-request, api, feed, network-profile

On individual sites, per user RSS and API feeds are available in addition to the activity profile tab. On global profiles, though, the only activity feed available is via the web interface. Could SE-wide activity feeds be made available via RSS and the API?

Answer (score 2):

The only way I've found to do such task is, go to [Filtered Questions](https://stackexchange.com/filters) and create a filter with "All Questions" on "All Sites", Add the rule! and save the changes:

[image]

How it looks after you Saved the Changes:

[image]